# Retrieving an element's value by string in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do the following in JQuery:

```
var test = "'#ISP'";

alert($(test).val());
```

I get "Syntax error, unrecognized expression."

I know i am missing something here.

Thanks alot!

Comment: remove the single quotes inside your string (or the double quotes around the outside). You are doing `$("'#ISP'").val()` when what I think you want is just `$('#ISP').val()`. Doing `var test = "#ISP"; $(test).val();` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var test = "ISP";
alert($("#"+test).val());
```

OR takeout the additional single quotes from your expression

```
var test = "#ISP";
alert($(test).val());
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/VwDyW/9/

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the 's inside the "s

```
var test = "#ISP";
alert($(test).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "#ISP";

alert($(test).val());
```

You've doubled up on your quotes. Take out the additional `''`.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/R7dae/